# How do I create a user in Oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Please tell me how to create user in Oracle 9i.

Comment: SO is not a substitute for google. Have you tried searching it even once?

Comment: please search the internet for "oracle 9i create user", you'll find all you need.

Comment: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/create_user.html

Answer (score 4):

Use the following to create a user called "username", whose password is "password":

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY password
```

### Reference:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm